# find and delete parent directories by the name without children directories with the same name

Tags: linux, find

I want to find directory 'node_modules' in the current directory. But I do not need nested 'node_modules'. For example, I do not need 'node_modules' in 'node_modules', only parents. When the directories are found, I want to delete them.

Comment: Similar question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42950501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for directory exist then delete.

```
[ -d node_modules ] && rm -rf node_modules
```

You can skip checking and use only `rm`:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Comment: What does `[ -d node_modules ]` do?

Comment: checking if the directory exists.